# Calculating cell size for raster when analyzing area not at equator using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, area, wgs84

How do I calculate the 'correct' cell size for a raster when analyzing an area not at the equator?

My goal is to project a land cover raster provided in GCS WGS84 to an equal area projection and 'accurately' calculate the area in hectares.

The land cover layer metadata (accompanying text file) states that it has a 300 m resolution, by which I assume they mean 300 m equivalent at the equator. Manually measuring the cell size near the equator seems to indicate that this could be true. However, my area of interest is centered on 15 North Lat., 96 East Long. and therefore each projected cell will cover a slightly different area.

The issue arises when I choose the cell size while projecting to equal area.

Comment: +1 This is a good simple question but it has a complex answer. One option is to dodge the issue by calculating areas in the original WGS84 coordinates. You can do this by computing zonal sums of cell areas. The cell areas can be found by multiplying the squared cellsize by a "shrinkage factor," which can be computed either with a spherical formula (it is the cosine of the latitude) or an ellipsoidal formula (a more complicated function of the latitude).

Comment: @whuber: thank you for the tip, that's an elegant solution. My initial thought is that this would be best for calculating the total regional area, by raster value? I also need to tabulate area by several area boundary zones (created by converting polygons to rasters with the same cell size as the land cover raster). As such, do you think it would it be easier to project to equal area, then calculate the area by land cover type/ spatial zone. Or, instead select raster cells by a location (spatial zone), extract by mask, and calculate using (cell size)^2 * Cos($$YMap * 0.0174532925)?

Comment: Ran out characters, to add: I have tried several methods, but I am trying to optimize this as I want to run it in a model. As such, the efficiency/logic is important to me.

Comment: To tabulate the areas, Dan, assuming the polygons do not overlap, compute a "zonal sum as table."  The polygons are the zones and the values to sum are the cosines.  Multiplying the zonal sums by the squared cellsize finishes the work.

Comment: I still do not quite follow. Zonal Statistics to Table using a sum of cosines based on the centroid of each polygon? I could not calculate this using cos("centroid field name here) * radian scaling factor. However, if I could, I do not understand why to sum cosines vs. cell count. As such, my final 'confused about area' question is (1) If I set the cell size as exactly 300m in equal area, will this be correct (i.e. represent 300m of area, regardless of latitude (it should, it is equal area?). (2) If not I should use your method, what (raster or vector) is the cosine calculated for?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how zonal summaries work.  The help page is at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Zonal_Statistics_works/009z000000wt000000/.  The cosine is exactly as you described in a previous comment: it is the cosine of the latitude grid.

Comment: This Question, despite a number of long Comments, has not had an Answer offered during the 6+ months that it has been here.  I notice that it has a number of questions contained within it, and as a result I am going to suggest that it be Closed as too broad.  Hopefully, this will stimulate the edit button being used to revise the Question, taking account of the Comments so far, into a more focussed and easily answered Question with a single question.  If so, then any questions thus removed may also become clearer and ready to be researched/asked separately.

Comment: Good point PolyGeo. I have shortened the question and it can be marked as closed.